# Showing (or not) a DIV or other HTML tag with JSTL if a variable exist

Tags: html, maven, jsp, spring-boot, jstl

I'm teaching myself how to work with JSTL.

I'm having problems with showing/not showing a DIV on my view when a variable is set o not from the Controller.

I'm working on a Spring Boot Maven project with Tiles for template management.

I set the variable just fine in my controller and I can see it just as well in my JSP view, and in this case show it in my DIV, as follows:

```
<c:if test="${!empty loggeduser}">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
            aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <strong>${loggeduser.email}</strong> Welcome to the new project!
    </div>
</c:if>
```

I would expect from this code that if the `loggeduser` variable is set, print the whole `DIV` tag with the "email Welcome" alert, just like the next image: [JSTL Working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/732vp.png)

By the other hand, if the `loggeduser` variable is NOT set, or not even exist, the `DIV` is not showed at all. But what I got when `loggeduser` doesn't exist is the `DIV` showing without the user email in the alert. Like the next image: [JSTL Not working as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1Ssn.png)

What I need is if I set a variable in my controller, show a complete DIV. If the variable is not set or doesn't exist, don't show/print the DIV.

P.S: This is my controller's method.

```
@PostMapping("/login/entry")
public String checkUserInfo(@Valid LoginUser loginUser, BindingResult bind, Model model) {
    logger.info("Entry");
    if (bind.hasErrors()) {
        logger.info("Bind has errors");
        model.addAttribute("hideTemplates", true);
        return "loginpage";
    }
    model.addAttribute("loggeduser", loginUser);
    return "aboutpage";
}
```

Comment: please try with test="${not empty loggeduser.email}"

Comment: Same result. `test="${not empty loggeduser.email}` and `test="${!empty loggeduser.email}` shows the same as the original `test="${!empty loggeduser}`. i.e, image number 2. I feel this shouldn't take that much work and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Tiles for templates management. The problem here is the JSP line `<%@ taglib prefix='c' uri='http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core' %>` is not included in cascade.

I solved my problem including that JSP line on every view file I had to use JSTL EL.